# Is this result correct? If so, where does it come from?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$ a^{nr} \mod 10 \equiv (a^n \mod 10 )^r \mod{10} $$

I'm not sure if this result holds, I haven't taken any real number theory.

My notation is most likely wrong however my thinking is the following

$$ 4^4 \mod10 \equiv 16^2 \mod10 \equiv (10 + 6)^2 \mod10 \equiv 6^2 \mod10 $$

I think this is true, I vaguely remember someone using it and it makes intuitive sense in base 10 at least (thinking about the last digit of the number). Does it hold for all bases?

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are right, that is what I mean. I edited my post.

Comment: As modified,  it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true for any base $b$, due to the following modular exponentiation rule
$$a^n \text{ mod } b = (a \text{ mod } b)^n \text{ mod } b$$
Apply this rule another time to $r$ and you get what you asked for.
The rule is explained here: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-exponentiation